# Sending a variable filename in php require from html

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this to call php files from html.

```
    <div id="readings">
        <?php require("readenglish.php"); ?>
        <?php require("readfrench.php"); ?>
        <?php require("readspanish.php"); ?>

    </div>
```

It'd be easy to get the date from the php file, but I must send the client-side date. I'd like to add a string with the client-side date to the file name.

```
    <div id="readings" style="position: relative; top: -380px; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; font: 0.9em arial, sans-serif;">
        <?php require("readenglish.php?date="+datestring); ?>
        <?php require("readfrench.php?date="+datestring); ?>
        <?php require("readspanish.php?date="+datestring); ?>

    </div>
```

Can this be done? I'd have to calculate the date in javascript. It'd be good if I did not have to go to ajax.  This would require completely changing the code structure.

Comment: You certainly will not be able to do it with Javascript.

Comment: Can milliseconds since 1970 be used?

Comment: you're trying to call javascript (client-side) at the time html is not even rendered yet / sent to client. Impossible.

Comment: You could always include some JavaScript in the PHP files to get the client-side date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple: COOKIES!

Answer (score 1):

**1/** you do NOT "call PHP from HTML", you add PHP content to your file and WHEN this PHP is parsed the server will send HTML to the client: HTML is the result of PHP process

**2/** getting the client-side date means that if your client changed its date to 1990, you will believe you got a request from the '90s, while your server's date is consistent with other dates it wrote in its logs

**3/** if you really need the client's date, your only choices are to use Ajax requests, GET parameters in URLs, or HTML forms with POST (or GET) data; and in all these cases you'll need to fill the data with Javascript's Date object

**solution A:** have a JS at the beginning of your page that reloads with the date if it wasn't given. Something like:

```
<?php if(empty($_REQUEST['date'])) { ?>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var d=new Date();
    window.location.href+='?date='+d.toISOString();
  </script>
  <?php die('Reloading with parameters...'); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

You can adapt this solution to fill a form and submit it all dynamically with JS if you prefer this way, but it's more to type...

**solution B:** use Ajax to retrieve and insert readxxx.php with a date argument passed, but you don't want to (though I don't see why it "would require completely changing the code structure")

**solution C (my favorite):** if you're using PHP 5.1+, you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']`, it will give you the server's time at which the client's request started (i.e. was received by the server)

solution D: use (i)frames built by JS, with the date as a parameter in the src attribute (*that* would require completely changing the code structure ^^)

Hope this helps.